# C# Abstract class, using anonymous instead of declaring concrete class?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-2.0, abstract-class, anonymous-methods

I have an abstract class and I would like to use it quickly by NOT create a concrete class that inherit the abstract class. Well, to define the abstract method anonymously.

Something like that:

```
           Command c = new Command(myObject){
               public override void Do()
               {
               }                   
            };
```

Is it possible in C# .net 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a type that wraps an action providing an implementation as such:

```
class ActionCommand
{
    private readonly Action _action;

    public ActionCommand(Action action)
    {
        _action = action;
    }

    public override void Do()
    {
        _action();
    }                   
};
```

This then can be used as so:

```
Command c = new Command((Action)delegate()
           {
              // insert code here
           });
```